# how to receive an array of instancied classes that share methods java

Tags: java, arrays, class, arguments, abstract-class

It is my first week learning abstract classes and I have the next exercise:

Supouse that I have the next example: I have 2 models, ElectricalBike and ManualBike. Both share all the atributes and methods with different implementations. But ElectricalBike has also batteryDuration

Because of that, I made an abstract class called Bike, that has all the shared attributes and the interface of the abstract methods.

Also I have a container class, lets call that BicycleShop that has a method that should receive an array of Bikes, both Electrical and Manual Bikes.

My question is, what does that method should receive? Because it wont be accurate the argument Bike[]. Should it receive 2 params, ElectricalBike[] and ManualBike[]?

Comment: What's wrong with `Bike[]`? Then you can put all subtypes of `Bike` (`ElectricBike` and `ManualBike`) into the array.

Comment: @MadyDaby So if I instance for example 2 ElectricalBike and 2 ManualBike and push them in the array, there wont be a problem? Because of course I cannot instance an abstract class like Bike

Comment: That should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Your method should receive a `Bike[]` argument. Because `ElectricalBike` and `ManualBike` extends `Bike`. So both of them are `Bike`.

And then in your method you can cast your argument `Bike[]`.

```
public void yourMethod(final Bike[] bikes) {
   if(bikes.length > 0) {
     if(bikes[0] instanceof ManualBike) {
        final ManualBike manualBikes = Arrays.copyOf(bikes, bikes.length, ManualBike.class);
        // do something
    } else if(bikes[0] instanceof ElectricalBike) {
        final ElectricalBike elecBikes = Arrays.copyOf(bikes, bikes.length, ElectricalBike.class);
        // do something
     } 
   }
 }
```